# How to Change DATA of each button in custom view

Tags: android

I have a custum view which also has button inside. I want to Change text of each button , for example I want to assign numbers to my button individually And manipulate it , what are the possible ways thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button button = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setText("Custom Text");

does that do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have made some changes on this code but this was the main idea which I looked for.